# `R`/`ggplot2`: Strangeness when combining individual `geom_histogram` layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm striving to replicate aspects of [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/6-reasons-why-you-should-stop-using-histograms-and-which-plot-you-should-use-instead-31f937a0a81c) nice demonstration using `R`/`ggplot2`.

For the first point (plotting different bin counts) I have managed nicely, but when replicating that approach for the second point (different maxima), it strangely fails and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I do for demonstrating the lack of robustness as pointed out in **2.** of above post:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
requireNamespace("kmed")

# Define the new maxima to be used
maxima <- c(197, 202, 213, 224)

# Replicate the UCI heart data set
m_df <- bind_rows(
  replicate(length(maxima), kmed::heart, simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    sm  = rep(maxima, each = nrow(kmed::heart)),
    fsm = paste("Maximum Edited to:", rep(maxima, each = nrow(kmed::heart))))

# Modify the maxima
m_df[which(m_df$thalach == max(m_df$thalach)), "thalach"] <- maxima

# Generate individual geom_histogram layers, forcing identical number of bins
m_lp_hist <- plyr::llply(maxima, function(b) {
  geom_histogram(
    data    = m_df %>% filter(sm == b),
    mapping = aes(x = thalach),
    bins    = 20)
  })

# Combine the layers
m_p_hist <- Reduce("+", m_lp_hist, init = ggplot2::ggplot())
m_p_hist +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(. ~ fsm, scales = "free_y") +
  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  ggplot2::labs(x = "Maximum Heart Rate Achieved", y = "Count")
```

When evaluating the resulting plot, the histograms are very similar (!), while stepping through the individual layers generated using `ggplot() + m_p_list[[1]]` etc. nicely shows the difference between the layers and thus the effect I intend to demonstrate (lack of robustness in histograms). What is going on here!?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to (what I think) you want. Try this instead:

```
m_p_hist +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(. ~ fsm, scales = "free") + # instead of free_y
  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  ggplot2::labs(x = "Maximum Heart Rate Achieved", y = "Count")
```

[image: result]

### Explanation

Your original code adds all 4 histogram layers into a single ggplot object before faceting them out into 4 separate plot panels again, **without allowing x-axis scales to vary across facets.** As a result, the x axis range / limits are calculated from the combined data of all 4 layers, and the 20 bins for each histogram are calculated from the same range.

By changing `scales = "free_y"` to `scales = "free"`, we allow x-axis scales to vary, and the 20 bins for each histogram are calculated from a different range of values.

By the way, it's not very clear to me why you'd want to create this via `facet_wrap`. I'd have gone with making 4 separate ggplot objects & stitching them together into a single chart afterwards for presentation purpose, which would have avoided the above issue all together. E.g.:

```
lapply(m_lp_hist, 
       function(p) ggplot() + 
         p + 
         labs(title = p$data$fsm[[1]]) +
         theme_bw()) %>%
  cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = ., nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In the interest of plotting homogeneity I try to stick with faceting wherever possible ... maybe occasionally overdoing it ;)